# How to put custom gap between interval for polling in Rxjs angular?

Tags: angular, rxjs, rxjs5, rxjs6

I would like to implement gap / delay between every interval call,
i have tried below but it seems not working.

```
  pollOnInterval(threshold = 4000): Observable<any> {
    let thresholdValue = threshold;
    const increaseBy = 2000;
    const maxCount = 10;
    return interval(thresholdValue).pipe(take(maxCount)).pipe(delay(increaseBy)).pipe(map(() => {
      thresholdValue = thresholdValue + increaseBy;
      console.log((new Date).toLocaleTimeString());
    }));
  }
```

**output**
2:34:21 PM
2:34:25 PM
2:34:29 PM
2:34:33 PM
2:34:37 PM
2:34:41 PM
2:34:45 PM
2:34:49 PM
2:34:53 PM
2:34:57 PM

**Edit -1** I have tried debounce and debouceTime, It didn't work too,
Stackbliz link: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-tinm4r?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

**Edit - 2** I need in below way
2:34:21 PM
2:34:27 PM
2:34:35 PM

Comment: You seem to increase the `thresholdValue` for each emission, but it will not be used again once it's used in the beginning to trigger the `interval`. What is the expected end-result here? Should be interval between each emission be 6s instead of 4s?

Comment: @MichaelD thresholdValue should increase by 2s on each call, So if it is not possible, can we put deplay in each interval, i tried by 2s in each interval, but that too didn't workout

Comment: i have updated question with expected result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. You could pipe all the operators in a single `pipe()`. Each operator doesn't require it's own pipe.
2. As mentioned in my comment, once the `interval()` is triggered using the `thresholdValue`, the subsequent changes to the `thresholdValue` variable won't have any effect on the `interval()` function. It will continue to emit for each time interval denoted by the `thresholdValue` *initally*.
3. At the moment the observable is emitting `undefined`s since nothing is returned from the `map`.
4. You need to use `concatMap` and pipe the delay to each emission individually. If not, the `delay` would be piped to the `interval` as a whole as seen in the question.

Try the following

```js
var { from, of, Observable, interval } = rxjs;
var { tap, delay, take, map, concatMap } = rxjs.operators;

var displayBox = document.getElementById('display');

function pollOnInterval(threshold = 4000) {
  let increaseBy = 4000;     // delay for first emission from `interval`
  const maxCount = 10;
  return interval(4000).pipe(
    concatMap(value => of(value).pipe(
      tap(() => 
        displayBox.innerHTML += `
          Interval: ${new Date().toLocaleTimeString()}; 
          Delay: ${increaseBy/1000}s
          <br />
        `
      ),
      delay(increaseBy)
    )),
    tap(() => increaseBy += 2000),     // <-- adjust `increaseBy`
    take(maxCount),
    map(() => new Date().toLocaleTimeString())
  );
}

pollOnInterval().subscribe({
  next: value => displayBox.innerHTML += `Subscription: ${value}<br /><hr>`,
  error: null,
  complete: () => displayBox.innerHTML += 'Observable complete.'
});
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/rxjs@6.6.0/bundles/rxjs.umd.min.js"></script>

<p id="display"></p>
```

Comment: Thank you so much. actually apis are responding very inconsistently so i was looking for this solution :)